# Meteor Ostrio:files server side image insertion

Tags: image, file, meteor, server

hi guys i am using ostrio:files package, i want to insert an image on the server side and get the image ID to input for my other data. But i couldn't find any documentation on insert the image to the collectoin on the server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor-Files documentation for uploading files from server -- https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/Write

```
 Images.write(binaryData, {
   fileName: 'something.png',
   type: 'image/png',
   meta: {owner: this.userId}, // or whatever you want to add
 }, (error, fileRef)=> {
    // do stuff with fileRef
 });
```

Also worth checking out `jalik:ufs` for an alternative package -- actively maintained and currently being used by RocketChat.

Comment: thank you, i saw the function but got the path wrong in meteor. i think next time i will go with jalik:ufs package as it seem more simpler